# How to export database correctly for local to online

Tags: php, sql, export, localhost, production

This process as a whole is fine... but I seem to have one small issue when I upload the database online.

If I create a theme and modify some options that's fine for the local version.

Once I upload the local version to my server, these values get reset to their defaults.

Does anyone know why this would occur? At the moment I export the database from PHPMyAdmin by selecting everything, ticking 'Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement' and then exporting it to a SQL file.

Thanks

Comment: You want to backup you db??

Comment: Can you confirm that the default values you mentioned are **really** in the production db now? Is it possible that are just stored somewhere else (like in files)? Did you develop the theme yourself?

Comment: I didn't develop it myself, I just changed stuff. I uploaded the site files and database at the same time, that's why it's doing my head in.

Answer (score 0):

What Options are you changing after upload to production server? I think after upload .sql file your website don't want appear in browser?

Check it:
After import your local .sql file to production server, log in to production/phpmyadmin website, go to wp_options and check values:

```
| option_id | option_name | option_value |
------------------------------------------ 
| id=1      | siteurl     | *check_it*   |
| id=37     | home        | *check_it*   |
```

Or maybe you have to check your wp_config.php file? 
Please let me know more info.

Comment: The upload works fine, the site works, config + install all goes well

For some reason though, it reverts back to old data for certain parts of the theme, like the footer, I don't see how or why